# Data Analysis vba on Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003, excel-2010

I had a macro in Excel 2003 that was using the data analysis add-in for vba to do some multi linear regressions.
I recently switched to 2010. The XXXXXXXX\ATPVBAEN.XLA cannot be found and my macro does not work (which doesn't mean that I can not use the usual excel data analysis tool).

No idea on to get this add-in where it should and also why it disapperead ....

Any help more than welcome!

Many thanks

Comment: See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/load-the-analysis-toolpak-HP010021569.aspx for install instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I'd encounter an "add-in connot be found", I'd check VBAProject-Links under the VBE (it's under Extra->Links or so). Usually some part was missing.

Also you could check the VBE-Menupoint "Add-Ins" and the Excel-Options "Add-Ins", where you can use "Manage: Excel-Add-Ins -> Go..." to activate Add-Ins like "Solver" and "Analysis Functions".

[image]

Hope this helps, hopefully there were not that much changes since 2007 ;)